# How to use oracle command like "break on" in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have execute a following query in MYSQL:

```
select fk_product_varient_id, fk_variant_value_id from prodvar order by fk_product_varient_id
```

and get following result:

[image]

But I want a output like this:

[image]

As "break on" command like in oracle is not working in MySQL. Can any one suggest how can I get desired output

Comment: I'm curious why

Comment: There is no equivalent in mysql - if you have a presentation layer do it there.

Answer (score 0):

You my use something like

```sql
select CASE WHEN p.fk_variant_value_id  IS NULL
            THEN ''
            ELSE fk_product_varient_id
            END fk_product_varient_id, 
       fk_variant_value_id 
from prodvar 
NATURAL LEFT JOIN (SELECT fk_product_varient_id, 
                          MIN(fk_variant_value_id) fk_variant_value_id
                   from prodvar
                   GROUP BY fk_product_varient_id) p 
order by prodvar.fk_product_varient_id, fk_variant_value_id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae50bfcb1f65573b954080647e5dea9e

But I agree with

> if you have a presentation layer do it there. – P.Salmon

Comment: The above query not working it is giving error "select is not valid for this position"

Comment: @MayankSrivastava My query cannot produce this error - maybe you have misprinted somewhere? Link to the fiddle added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` in latest versions

```
select case when rn=1 then fk_product_varient_id else '' end fk_product_varient_id, fk_variant_value_id
from (
  select fk_product_varient_id, fk_variant_value_id,
      row_number() over(partition by fk_product_varient_id order by fk_variant_value_id) rn
  from prodvar) t
order by fk_product_varient_id, fk_variant_value_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with row number but no subquery is needed:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by fk_product_variant_id order by fk_variant_value_id) = 1
             then fk_variant_value_id
        end) as fk_variant_value_id,
       fk_variant_value_id
from prodvar
order by fk_product_variant_id, fk_variant_value_id;
```

However, you might find that one row per `fk_product_variant_id` works just as well:

```
select fk_product_variant_id,
       group_concat(fk_variant_value_id order by fk_variant_value_id) as fk_variant_value_ids
from prodvar
group by fk_product_variant_id;
```